# chickenpox virus

Tags: personality

If someone who is recently having chickenpox (2-3 day) ,comes in contact with me (I have already had it in past). Can the virus comes in my body again? Most importantly can virus enter in to third person through me?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this site](http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/ask-the-expert/infections/a5542/am-i-infectious-after-contact-with-chickenpox/) the answer is "no" you aren't going to be infectious.  In part this is because once you get chicken pox you will always have some of the virus in you for the rest of your life.  Later in life the virus can become re-activated and is called shingles.

Getting a fresh exposure to chicken pox should not have any effect on your status as a carrier though.